# postfix or sendmail monitoring

Tags: postfix, sendmail

I’m interested in alerting a support team in email when mail is backing up and not being relayed as expected, ie sending is delayed. I tried in nagios, there isn't any solution. I tried with logwatch, it is not the desired one.

The desired solution:
If the mail is not sent "status=sent (250 Ok)", then alert in mail.
It is easy, the problematic part is to avoid the repetition. So once an alert found in case of the second check not sent any alert relates to this.

How can be this done ?

Maybe postfix has an own solution ?

Comment: What is the method you're using to send the alert mail? Is it possible to have a specific email account/specific identifying information attached to a message so that you can filter it out in the method you're using?

Answer (score 2):

SMTP is not designed for real-time & low-latency communications!
Even when a message has left your server typically it is not delivered yet to the recipients INBOX, it might still be undergoing processing in a remote spam and/or AV filter.

Since [greylisting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greylisting) is both quite effective and common even temporary errors are not an issue.

Simply monitor the size of the mailqueue, depending on your usage pattern only events with queue's above 100's or 1000's might be of concern and indicative of real problems...

Comment: Although it is true what you are saying, it does not answer the question. OP wants to monitor delayed/deferred mails.

Comment: Unless you generate large numbers of messages or send very large email messages a mailqueue will often almost entirely consist of delayed/deferred email messages...  So IMHO that makes a sensible monitor and much easier to implement than parsing log files. Sendmail comes with `mailq` and Postfix with `postqueue -p` . Additionally Nagios already has quite a number of plugins around those commands.

Comment: IMHO on most servers 95%-99% of messages is delivered/relayed below 2-5 minutes. AFAIK some email servers (MS Exchange?) can periodically send message to themselves via another email server. It allows to monitor "health" of the most important email delivery paths.  It is not a foolproof check but it is quite easy to implement and worth to monitor (IMHO),

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with the repetition should be manageable if you are willing to create an additional file/log somewhere.  For example go through the normal steps to send the alert email, then after the message is successfully sent add an additional line to the script that writes the timestamp and maybe some other info to a new log file something like this would work:

```
echo $(date +%s),sent_queuealert >> /path/to/postfix/logs/sentalerts.log
```

Which will store the unix date stamp and the action taken.  Now that the log file is written some additional logic in if-else statements is all that is required to control if the message is sent, here is a simple example

```
#!/bin/bash
lastalert=$(grep "sent_queuealert" ./sentalerts.log |tail -n1 |cut -d"," -f1)
ctime=$(date +%s)
dtime=$(expr $ctime - $lastalert)
if [ "$dtime" -lt 250 ]
then
    echo "Too soon to send"
    echo $(date +%s),skip_send >> sentalerts.log
else
    echo "place holder for alert sender"
    echo $(date +%s),sent_queuealert >> sentalerts.log
fi
```

That is a pretty rough version but it should be easy enough to modify for your purposes.  Using cron to run the appropriate script every few minutes would allow you to check the log file and not necessarily rely on the internal mechanisms in postfix.  There is some interesting info on [monitoring postfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226699/how-to-monitor-postfix-mta-status) in that answer.  Combining that knowledge with some sort of timestamped log checking might yield a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Email monitoring should start with a few simple things:

- are the mail servers accepting connection on SMTP or SMTPS ports?
- are the mail servers accepting new mail for your users?  relayed users?
- is there free disk space on the mail server?
- are the queues filling up?

Once you've got the basics covered then consider expanding to also

- send an email every *n* minutes to a role account then make sure that account has fresh email in the last n*2 minutes.
- watch how much CPU is being used by `postfix` and its helpers
- graph how much spam you are filtering
- graph delivery latency
- add alerts around the metrics